# Loading QDialog is blank when showed

Tags: c++, loading, qdialog

I am working on a code that allows the user to control a piezo (PZ193E) in a MainWindow created with Qt Designer form.

However, when I call the function designed to connect the piezo to the computer (from an external library given by the constructor) my UI freeze until the connection is established.

I am trying to display a QDialog with a QLabel in it, telling the user to wait while the connection is processing, but when I do so, the QDialog shows up but without the label. It is only displayed when the connection is established and when the QDialog can close.

Here is how I coded my dialog :

```
In the .h :
QDialog *_waitQD = new QDialog;
QVBoxLayout *_waitQVBL = new QVBoxLayout;
QLabel *_waitQL = new QLabel("Loading...");

In the .cpp : 
_waitQD->setMinimumSize(QSize(95,35));
_waitQVBL->addWidget(_waitQL);
_waitQD->setLayout(_waitQVBL);
```

And then I call :

```
_waitQD->show();
if (_piezo.connected()) // bool funtion that return true if the connection is established
      _waitQD->close();
```

This is what it looks like:
[image: Blank QDialog]

Comment: it works on Qt 5.7 msvc2015 (it should be "_waitQD->show();")

Comment: I made the mistake while copying my code, I use the "->"in the real one ! but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution is not blocking the main thread while establishing the connection; the workaround is adding `QApplication::processEvents();` after the call to show

Answer (score 0):

you need to call app.exec()

```
#include <QApplication>

#include <QDialog>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QDialog *_waitQD = new QDialog;
    QVBoxLayout *_waitQVBL = new QVBoxLayout;
    QLabel *_waitQL = new QLabel("Loading...");

    _waitQD->setMinimumSize(QSize(95,35));
    _waitQVBL->addWidget(_waitQL);
    _waitQD->setLayout(_waitQVBL);

    _waitQD->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```